# Get data from webpage using HtmlElement?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, web

I'm trying to get data from a game site into my winforms application. The page I'm looking to withdraw data from is this: http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Eternal+Oblivion

My winforms program has a search bar connected to a webbrowser. In this search bar I can type in a name, for example the game character name "Eternal Oblivion". When I hit search it goes to that page (example: http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Eternal+Oblivion).

In my winforms application I have a table like that contains Name, Sex, Vocation, Level. Only those 4 (to start with) - it is basically a copy of his profile page. But how can I get the data into my program? I want it to look like this in my program:

```
Name: Eternal Oblivion
Sex: Male
Vocation: Knight
Level: 297
```

This is the code I'm currently using but it doesn't work. Seems to be a tricky one because the website doesn't use any like style name or w/e on the table tags. Why isn't bgcolor working? And also, my code wouldn't work since then it would only repeat the same thing on like color A and same on color B. But as you see on the website, http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Eternal+Oblivion the color is on every 2nd line. How would I do that?

```
if (this.browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement cell in this.browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tr"))
                {
                    string cls = cell.GetAttribute("bgcolor");
                    if (cls.StartsWith("#F1E0C6"))
                    {
                        dynamic oldname = cell.InnerText;
                        string[] strings = oldname.Split('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
                        string charnameonly = strings[1];
                        labelName.Text = charnameonly.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (cls.StartsWith("#D4C0A1"))
                    {
                        dynamic oldsex = cell.InnerText;
                        string[] strings = oldsex.Split('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
                        string charsexonly = strings[1];
                        labelSex.Text = charsexonly.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach. Once you have the HTML code of the page in a String, then split based on what you are looking for. For example, to get the character name:

```
string name = htmlCode
     .Split(new string[] {"Name:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
     .Split('>')[2]
     .Split('<')[0];
```

is not clean and nice, but works and will do the same for all the other values you are looking for, just change the "Name:" for "Sex:", "Vocation:", etc...